# Prevent instances from overlapping gamemaker studio

Tags: ai, path-finding, game-maker

I have a game where multiple instances of an enemy move towards a player in their step process.  There can be as many as 50 instances on screen.

The issue is that the instances all end up in 1 big group as they follow the player.
I would like to prevent them from getting more than 2 pixels of each other.

the code is as follows:

```
if distance_to_object(player) < 160 {
  direction = ppoint_direction(x,y, player.x, player.x, player.y)
  p_potential_step(x,y, player.x, true);
}
```

If I put a distance check of 2px in this code, the instance starts making jerky movements and spins. I would like the instance to continue following the player, but just not allow themselves to overlap.

Comment: You might also want to check out [this blog post](http://www.gamasutra.com/blogs/TylerGlaiel/20121007/178966/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had success preventing this by adding a collision event with the enemies own type.

Inside this event, make the enemy step into a direction where there is space. You can determine that via `place_free` for example. In my case of a space game, it is rather easy since I can just let them step in any direction until they have enough space to operate.

But even a simple

```
x = xprevious
y = yprevious
```

can help a lot with this issue.